# Where can we find out about changes?

Tags: support, meta

Where can we find out what changes have or are in progress to be made within the Stack Exchange network as a result of a question asked here or otherwise?

Comment: You could also post a [feature-request] asking for an official changelog on Meta.SE.

Answer (score 17):

You may look at an unofficial list of new features and various changes to Stack Overflow and the Stack Exchange network at: [Recent feature changes to Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59445/recent-feature-changes-to-stack-exchange)

You may also search for posts which are marked as [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) or [status-planned](/questions/tagged/status-planned).